# PresenceStatus using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Presence dll

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lync, ucma

I have a logged in user to Microsoft Office Communicator whose presence is 
**available**.

I want to get the presence of this user in the application.

Which method should I use in `Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Presence` class to actually get the status of users?

I am not exactly getting the method to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0):

There is sample code which outlines how to do this on MSDN: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Lync-2010-Working-With-be423675

There is also a walkthrough video which covers monitoring someone's presence here: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/04/ucma-101-training-video/